# How to change IntelliSense autocomplete in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, intellisense, game-development

When I write commonly used methods such as Start() or Update() IntelliSense autocompletes them as **private void Start() { }**. I don't put private in front of methods or variables because they're private by default, so it's quite tedious having to remove it dozens of times per day.

So how do I change that autocomplete template?

Comment: Is this C# or C++ (or C++ CLI)?

Comment: it is C#, OP used the wrong tag

Comment: May I know if the answer can solve the issue? if not, please share it in here, we can work together to figure it out. If it works you can click '✔' to mark the reply as the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the Unity settings in visual studio (Tools > Options > Tools for Unity)
and change the value of `Unity Messages scope` from `Private` to `Default`

[image: Visual Studio settings]